# How to stub a instance method for a specific instance?

Tags: ruby, stubs

I have below case,

```
class Schools::Status
  def initialize(school)
    @school = school
  end

  def active?
    true
  end
end
```

Now, I want to stub `active?` method for a specific school.

One way to have like this

```
Schools::Status.new(school).stubs(:active?).returns(false)
```

But my use case is different, I have search result of schools and I want to filter that result based on `active?` value as below:

```
schools.select { |s| Schools::Status.new(school).active? }
```

In above case, specifically I want to stub `active?` for certain instance.

Comment: AFAIK `stub` works only for `double` object you create for mocking in rspec. Or maybe I misunderstood your question? What are you exactly looking for?

Comment: I have schools collection which will be selected for schools based on active? condition. so for a specific school i wanted to stub `active?` method of `Schools::Status` class.

Comment: And you need this behavior in your specs?

Answer (score 3):

Just monkey-patch your class in the spec.The more rspec-way would be to use `any_instance` with `stub` but the problem is you cannot get access to the `self` of the stubbed instance so you practicly have no information about the `school` and you cannot access it in that block.
Example:

```
Status.any_instance.stub(:active?) { # no way to access school }
```

Comment: actually there is no need to monkey match `any_instance` for `self`. Please see the answer where particular instance can be stubbed.

Answer (score 1):

I found answer on myself and putting here so that others can be benefited

Lets say, I have `school` for which `active?` method of `Schools::Status` is to be stubbed.

In order to achieve this, 
First we need to stub `new` method of `Schools::Status` so that it will return Schools::Status instance which we want and it can be done as below -

```
status = Schools::Status.new(school)
# now whenever Schools::Status instance getting created for ours school 
# it will return our defined status instance
Schools::Status.stubs(:new).with(school).returns(status)
```

Secondly, we have to stub `active?` method for status instance -

```
status.stubs(:active?).returns(false)
```

Now, filter will reject specified school for which `active?` method returns false